# Select distinct from multiple columns and its matching values sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table named `Orders`. 
Each row of the table represents an order made by a customer.

**prod** means **product**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| prod_1      | prod_1_qty  | prod_2      |prod_2_qty   | prod_3      | prod_3_qty  |
|-------------------------------------------------------|---------------------------|
| chair       | 3           | board       |9            | bed         |4            |
| board       | 8           | door        |2            | desk        |2            |
| chair       | 2           | window      |1            | door        |6            |
| desk        | 4           | chair       |3            | sofa        |1            |
```

I would like to write a query that returns the quantity of each `product` ordered like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| product     | product_qty |
|---------------------------|
| chair       | 8           |
| board       | 17          |
| door        | 8           |
| window      | 1           |
| sofa        | 1           |
| bed         | 4           |
| desk        | 6           |
```

Is there any way to achieve this using `T-SQL`, and if so, what is the query one would use to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT x.prod
     , SUM(x.prod_qty) AS total
FROM (
       SELECT prod1 AS prod, prod_qty AS total FROM table
          UNION ALL
       SELECT prod2 AS prod, prod_qty AS total FROM table 
          UNION ALL
       SELECT prod3 AS prod, prod_qty AS total FROM table
     ) x 
GROUP BY x.prod
```